# Custom Image on WKInterfaceMenuItem not Showing

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

I am trying to get my menu set up for my WatchKit app.  According to the documentation on the Watch HIG, the Canvas size for the image should be 80 x 80.  I did this, set my MenuItem as Custom, and put in the image I created, however nothing shows up.  What am I doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to check:

1) Is the image part of your WatchKit app's bundle/image catalog? Anywhere else and it won't work.

2) Are you setting this programatically? If so, double-check that you're referencing the correct image.

Comment: Issue was #1, was added to the iOS target by mistake.

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted :-)